# Predicate function as argument

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, predicate

I have a function that will take another function and if the function I pass as an argument is true then it does something and if it is false then it does something else, but how do I specify it so that the function that is passed as an argument is a function that returns a `bool`?

```
def a_function(function, value):
    if function(value):
       do this
    else:
       do this
```

but if "function" is not a function that returns a bool then my code doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution using `isinstance` would work. Run [this code](http://codebunk.com/b/-JJzQlUmKV10CO5Lps_k).

```
def fn(function, value):
    result = function(value)
    if not isinstance(result, bool):
       raise ValueError("function did not return a bool")
    if result:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

fn(lambda x: True, [1, 2, 3])
fn(sum, [1, 2, 3])
```

A while ago I wrote [a post discussing Guido's multimethods](http://speak.codebunk.com/post/77084204957/pattern-matching-in-python) and using them to do pattern matching on function arguments.